# Java Interface extending Class

Tags: java

In my code I have an interface Component to define types. I want to extend that interface with a class InputComponent that has to implement the framework of an API's InputListener.

I'm really at a loss and don't know what to do. To clarify:

```
public class InputListener implements EventListener {} // this is the API's implementation (details hidden)

public interface Component {}
public interface InputComponent extends Component implements XYZ {} // this should somehow work with the InputListener class
```

Could somebody give me some resources (links, information, anything at all) on how to do this?

Comment: An interface is a design-by-contract approach. Also it represents a has-a relationship. Why do you think it necessary to extend an interface? Makes no sense at all.

Comment: I want to use a List<Component> and put all the components in there. Is there no way to do this, considering the problem above?

Comment: Component is an interface. So creating a list of components means you can add classobjects to that list that "implements Component"

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I tried to approach the problem in a wrong way.

Comment: If you want, the web is full with tutorials on has-a and is-a relations in OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can only extend other interfaces.

Interfaces cannot extend classes.

Interfaces do not implement other interfaces.